# How can one pass a dynamic array out of a method in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, null

I am trying to pass a pair of pointers to an array, read a file containing arrays of points, dynamically allocate arrays to hold those points, and access those arrays outside of the function by means of the pointers. I am using the Visual C++ 2008 Express compiler.

---

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
// point object
class GLintPoint{
public:
    GLint x,y;
    GLintPoint(){x=0;y=0;}
    GLintPoint(GLint X,GLint Y){x=X;y=Y;}
};
// pass name of the file followed by points to return
void readPolyLineFile(char * filename, GLintPoint ** polylines, GLint *polyCount)
{
    fstream inStream;
    inStream.open(filename, ios::in);
    if(inStream.fail()) return;
    // number of arrays, size of each array,, values of each point
    GLint numpolys, numLines, x, y;
    inStream >> numpolys;
    polylines = new GLintPoint*[numpolys];
    polyCount = new GLint[numpolys];

    for(int j=0;j < numpolys; j++)
    {
        inStream >> numLines;
        polyCount[j] = numLines;
        polylines[j] = new GLintPoint[numLines];

        for(int i=0;i<numLines;i++)
        {
            inStream >> x >> y;
            polylines[j][i].x = x;
            polylines[j][i].y = y;
        }
    }
    inStream.close();
    return;
}
```

polylines is an array to hold point arrays, which is the data I want. polyCount is the size of each individual array within polylines.

So far whenever I run this function, it runs as expected, but when it returns to the line from where I called it, the pointersE have been set to null and the arrays are presumably deleted. Why is that my function is deleting these arrays and how can I alter this behavior to maintain the dynamic array upon returning? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using `boost::shared_ptr<T>` / `boost::shared_array<T>` / `std::shared_ptr<T, D>`?

Comment: You should really be using a `std::vector<GLintPoint>` or nested equivalent instead of an array. That will also simplify your allocation (which is unsafe and potentially leaky as is) and returning (just return the vector and MSVC will perform RVO).

Comment: +1 to std::vector. Kill all the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using C++ you can either pass the arguments as references or add another pointer redirection.

Passing as reference:

```
void readPolyLineFile(char * filename, GLintPoint ** &polylines, GLint *&polyCount)
```

Then you can use the variables "as is".

The other solution is a more "pure C" solution, and is to add another pointer redirection:

```
void readPolyLineFile(char * filename, GLintPoint ***polylines, GLint **polyCount)
```

Then you have to use pointer dereferencing when assigning to the variables:

```
*polylines = new GLintPoint*[numpolys];
*polyCount = new GLint[numpolys];

// ...

(*polyCount)[j] = numLines;

// ... etc...
```

Comment: Much thanks, @Joachim! This had been giving me quite a bit of trouble.